# Can I disable viewport units in chrome (for debugging fallbacks)?

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome

I have found that my viewport-based layout so meticulously prepared looks terrible in android's default web browser and, as far as I have been able to gather, the problem might be due to the support for vw and vh units in such context, so I am thinking of implementing a script-based workaround. However, in order to test it, it would be helpful if I could disable the viewport units in my development environment, currently Chrome on Windows 7.

Does anybody know whether it is possible and how, or maybe a simple alternative? Thanks!